# How to return values from recursive function to array

Tags: recursion, julia

```
function nestedLoop(depth::Integer, n::Integer, symbArr, len::Integer, k::Integer, num_arr)
  for i = k:len
    num_arr[depth-n+1] = symbArr[i]
    n == 1 && println(num_arr)
    (n > 1) && nestedLoop(depth, n-1, symbArr, len, i, num_arr)
  end
end

function combwithrep(symbArr, n::Integer)
  len = length(symbArr)
  num_arr = Array(eltype(symbArr),n)
  nestedLoop(n, n, symbArr, len, 1, num_arr)
end
@time combwithrep(["+","-","*","/"], 3)
```

I have some troubles with returning values from elementary recursive function, that computes combinations with repetitions. I can't realize how to commit replacement of `println` with some return to array in `combwithrep()` function. I have failed to use tasks for this also. The best result is to obtain iterator over this values, but it is not possible in recursion, isn't it?

I feel that the answer is simple, and i don't understand something about recursion.

Comment: Would including and returning an accumulator in your tail recursion give you want you want?

Comment: Following the [`Combinations` iterator model](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/combinatorics.jl#L172) to create your own `Type`, `length`, `start`, `next`, and `done` for an iterator would be a good exercise.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Accumulator is a kind of counter, if we are speaking about one and the same. Actually, I need combinations themselves, not a counter. But it seems I understood u not correctly about this. Could u show a few lines of code for example?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Speaking about combinations from combinatorics.jl, yes, you are right about good exercise. I knew about this iterator implemetation. But it is done without recursion. I can't understand how to implement it in recursion case. Algorithm  rewriting is surely possible, but i'm trying to clarify situation with recusive functions. First of all, I want answer for simple question: is it possible to do iterator from recursive function? Thanks for help.

Comment: I've posted _a_ way to return _all_ the combinations.  An iterator is possible, but that should probably be a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly not optimal, but it's functional.

```
julia> function nested_loop{T <: Integer, V <: AbstractVector}(depth::T, n::T, symb_arr::V, len::T, k::T, num_arr::V, result::Array{V,1})
           for i = k:len
               num_arr[depth-n+1] = symb_arr[i]
               n == 1 ? push!(result, deepcopy(num_arr)) : nested_loop(depth, n-1, symb_arr, len, i, num_arr, result)
           end
       end
nested_loop (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function combwithrep(symb_arr::AbstractVector, n::Integer)
           len = length(symb_arr)
           num_arr = Array(eltype(symb_arr),n)
           result = Array{typeof(num_arr)}(0)
           nested_loop(n, n, symb_arr, len, 1, num_arr, result)
           return result
       end
combwithrep (generic function with 1 method)

julia> combwithrep(['+', '-', '*', '/'], 3)
20-element Array{Array{Char,1},1}:
 ['+','+','+']
 ['+','+','-']
 ['+','+','*']
 ['+','+','/']
 ['+','-','-']
 ['+','-','*']
 ['+','-','/']
 ['+','*','*']
 ['+','*','/']
 ['+','/','/']
 ['-','-','-']
 ['-','-','*']
 ['-','-','/']
 ['-','*','*']
 ['-','*','/']
 ['-','/','/']
 ['*','*','*']
 ['*','*','/']
 ['*','/','/']
 ['/','/','/']
```

Comment: U are my hero ;D Many thanks. I tried to do similar thing but without `deepcopy()`. Result was frustrating. Maybe I will open next thread about recursive iterators later.